# I upgraded from .NET 5 to .NET 6 and now getting SqlNullValueException from a LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I just upgraded a project from .NET 5 to the .NET 6 preview and started using Visual Studio 2022. But I'm getting a SqlNullValueException that I wasn't getting before. And it's not making sense to me.

Here is the LINQ query:

```
var clients = _dbContext.AppUserAppUsers
            .Where(x => x.AppUserParentId == designerId
                        && x.ChildAppUser.AppUserRole == AppUserRole.Client)
            .Include(x => x.ChildAppUser.Profile)
            .Select(x => x.ChildAppUser)
            .AsNoTracking();

return clients.ToList();
```

The AppUserAppUsers entity is a many-to-many model for AppUsers. I'm using the
[Table-per-hierarchy pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance)
So I have AppUserBase abstract class and DesignerModel and ClientModel both extend that class.

```
public class AppUserAppUser
    {
        public int AppUserParentId { get; set; }

        public int AppUserChildId { get; set; }

        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public AppUserBase ParentAppUser { get; set; }

        public AppUserBase ChildAppUser { get; set; }
    }
```

Again, all this works beautifully in .NET 5!

The call to ToList() throws this exception:

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException
  HResult=0x80131931
  Message=Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
  Source=Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.ThrowIfNull()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Design2WorkroomApi.Repository.AppUserRepository.GetClientsByDesignerId(Int32 designerId) in C:\Users\davew\source\repos\Design2WorkroomApi\Design2WorkroomApi\Repository\AppUserRepository.cs:line 65
   at Design2ClientAPI.Controllers.ClientsController.GetClientsByDesignerId(Int32 designerId) in C:\Users\davew\source\repos\Design2WorkroomApi\Design2WorkroomApi\Controllers\ClientsController.cs:line 56
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
```

If I take out the Include and the Select calls this works fine. But either one and the LINQ statement returns null.

In the .NET 5 version, this same method with the same parameter works just fine. And I have used similar code many times before with no problems.

Obviously, something in .NET 6 has changed to cause this, but I don't know what it is.

Here are my Entity Framework Core packages. I had the same issue before I upgraded these packages.

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0-rc.2.21480.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0-rc.2.21480.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.0-rc.2.21480.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.0-rc.2.21480.5">
```

Comment: 1) Something wrong with `AppUserBase` some string field is null in database but EF do not know about this, check your model. 2). `Include` and `Select` two opposite operators, if you have `Select`, `Include` can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks. I had a string property in AppUser that had null values. I made it nullable and it works now. But I don't understand this. Strings in C# have always been nullable by default as far as I know. And like I said this worked fine in .NET 5. So confused right now but it's working. Also, I did remove the Include statement but in no longer included the profile. So I added it back. That is working fine. I don't know a better way to do that.

Comment: It is made for performance reason. If EF for each string field will check for DB Null, it will slowdown performance.

Comment: Thanks, I'm less confused now. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.Include()`,  it is not needed in this particular case and it can cause the error which you are getting.

The new query should simply look something like:

```
var clients = _dbContext.AppUserAppUsers
            .Where(x => x.AppUserParentId == designerId
                        && x.ChildAppUser.AppUserRole == AppUserRole.Client)
            .Select(x => x.ChildAppUser)
            .AsNoTracking();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't include the profile when I leave out the include statement. I tried it without but had to put it back. The exception was caused by a string property not being nullable, which I've never seen before.  Are strings no longer nullable by default in C#? Did they take a play from Kotlin?

Comment: @DavidEvans It depends, you can enable null checks in your project by adding `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in the csproj file (inside the first `<PropertyGroup>` tags) that will force your code to check instances where values might be null and warn you about it. Once that is done, you have two options either declare a default `string.Empty` value for the `Profile` property or make it nullable `string?`. I hope that helps.

Comment: It does. Thanks!

Comment: The line <Nullable>enable</Nullable> is there by default in a new .NET 6 project. It isn't in a new .NET 5. If I remove that line and set the string property as not nullable, it works fine. So that is why it worked in the .NET 5 version and not the .NET 6. (I created a new project for .NET 6 and did some copy n pasting.) That's why I was really confused. Worked in .NET 5 and not .NET 6. So mystery solved thanks to you. I will leave Nullable enabled and make the string properties nullable.